# Using network link along with self-signed web server

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I have a simple KML view in a browser using Google Earth plugin. The simple KML is just a network link to a placemark being served by a web server, so the URL to the data is something like https://foo.com/data. But this does not work. The plugin never loads the data from the server.

I am fairly confident that the problem is due to the SSL certificate of the site not being real, i.e., it is self-signed. So I suspect the GE plugin quietly ignores the link.

Is there any way to tell GE plugin to ignore invalid SSL certificates? I have to be able to use the https protocol and since it is a development server, I can 't get a real certificate for it either.

I appreciate any ideas you may have.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the Google Earth desktop client able to open the KML at the same URL?

Answer (score 0):

there is a couple of things that could be effecting the network link.

If you are requiring authentication to access the kml file, older versions of google earth didn`t pass standard cookies in network link requests making security tricky.

The newest version of google earth client  6.2 (beta) seems to be passing the cookies if initiate a browser session via the built in browser to the client.  I havn`t tried network links with the plugin though.

The other thing is to make sure earth is hitting the server, if you are not using fiddler is a good tool to see what traffic you are generating and if the network link is updating.

Another hack may be to use a standard ajax request in the browser to hit, the kml endpoint and pass the response to earth using parse kml.

Another method if you are tracking just a few points, just request the updated coordinates a and have those returned, and update the point coordinates via javascript.